# How to add transition between two bootstrap navbar classes

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this bootstrap navigation on my page:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            ...
            ...
```

and I also have this jQuery code that switched between the fixed and classic navbar.

```
            $(document).on("scroll",function(){
                if($(document).scrollTop()>20) {
                    $("nav").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                } else {
                    $("nav").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                }
            });
```

While it switched fine, the change is rather abrupt and I would like to add transition to it. I tried adding this to css but it does not work. How can I transition between them?

```
nav{
transition: all 1s;
-moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example code is at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/qaBywr)**

HTML:

```
  <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</nav>

<!-- Demo Header -->
<header>
  <h1>Bootstrap Collapsing Animated Navigation</h1>
</header>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
   if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
     $("nav").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
   } else {
     $("nav").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
   }
 });
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default {
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -moz-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

header {
  padding: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/800?image=974
);
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

I hope it might be helpful.

Enjoy :)

Comment: While this is good, it does not really answer my question. I want it to transition between two different styles. I have the classic one "navbar navbar-inverse" that puts the navbar in the middle at the top and I want it to transition to "navbar-fixed-top". Your solution has both bars fixed on top, it just makes the height smaller on scrolling. This is exactly what I found in some tutorials online, but it did not work on the exact solution I am working on. I hope I said it clearly this time :) If you need it, I  can send you a full html code of the navigation I have, but it is kinda long.

Comment: Yes you can share your code in CODEPEN or JSFIDDLE. It will help in better understanding and debugging the problem.

Comment: well I found out I cannot simply share it on jsfiddle, since it does not support bootstrap framework. But basically I am using this framerwork: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar and it has two basic navbars. One that is fixed to top when you use class "navbar-fixed-top" and other when you use "navbar-default". They both work on their own. One fixes it on top of the page, the other have it in the middle with margins on all sides. So what I want is to switch from the classic view to the fixed view. I imagine the navigation to widen itself and fixes to top when you scroll.